# How can we solve substring matching check using Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I learnt program to find longest common substring using dynamic programming. Can we also use dynamic programming to find out if substring exists in a string?

I tried it. However, it seem to be making things more complicated!

Below is the pseudo code of what I tried.

String : Helello

Substring : llo

f(n) : returns false if character of substring not found or the positions of found places

f(0) = matching indexes or false

f(1) = next index of f(0) index is substring[1] or false

f(2) = next index of f(1) index is substring[1] or false

f(n) = f(n-1) followed by next index of current char or false

Calling : substring('hello', 2, 'el' );

```
substring(str, n, substring)
{
        if(n == 0)
        {
                for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
                {
                        if(str[i] == substring[n])
                                pos[] = i; //append i to positions array
                }
                if(pos) return pos;
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
                indexes = substring(str, n-1, substring);
                if(indexes)
                {
                        foreach(indexes as index)
                        {
                                if(str[index+1] == substring[n])
                                        return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: Here's a recursive definition: "A function `f(needle, haystack)` determines whether substring needle appears within a larger string haystack by returning true if either `needle == haystack(1:length(needle))` or `f(needle, haystack(2:end))`"  Now apply DP.

Comment: So you posted psuedo code that is something like your real code. Post real code that compiles without errors and warnings please - unless it's compiler errors that are foxing you.

Comment: *"I learnt program to find longest common substring using dynamic programming. Can we also use dynamic programming to find out if substring exists in a string?"* How can you possibly do the former without being able to do the latter?

Comment: `false`, `true` and `pos` are different type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can solve that problem with DP.

For instance let's say you have a sentence S, and word W. You wanna to check if the given word W is a substring of sentence S. You can do that with DP only if the length of LCS(longest common substring) is equal to length of word W, which means that W is actually that LCS. Complexity is O(N * M) where N is length of S and M is length of W.

You can do much better with KMP, in O(N + M), or hashing.